# Not enough free space on /boot to upgrade - already cleaned old kernels!

Tags: boot, partitioning, upgrade, kernel, updates

I have an Ubuntu base update which can't be installed because

> The upgrade needs a total of 178 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 54.7 M of disk space on '/boot'.

I know this is a FAQ and I've been browsing countless StackExchange threads and forum posts. They all suggest to clean old kernels in various ways. But I have none there except the very last one (see screenshots below).

Trash is empty (12K). `/boot` size is 250M.

Here is the result of `ls -lh -a` on `/boot`

[image: ls -lh -a]

And here the result of `df -h` with info on `/boot`

[image: df -h]

Why does it say total 97M? And with `df` it says 107M...

Comment: This is a known bug. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1465050

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok I figured it out and I'm leaving this answer here for whomever bumps in the same problem and despite cleaning the old kernels from `/boot` still has problems with the GUI updater

I found out that the GUI updater might stick with the same old notice even after you have cleaned space in `/boot`. Restarting didn't help.. This might as well be a bug?

How I solved:

went to terminal and manually installed the necessary packages, like:

`sudo apt-get install linux-generic`

check with `sudo apt-get upgrade` if you have any more to install who have been kept back and install those too, in my case I had also to run:

`sudo apt-get update linux-tools-virtual`

after that I did a

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

later tried to run again the GUI updater... it will say everything's ok up to date and invite to restart since there's a new kernel

I was able to solve since although far from being an expert I know my way around the command line. I'll file a report to Ubuntu in case this is a bug with the GUI updater.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update linux-tools-virtual` Does not work. `The update command takes no arguments`

Comment: I have done it without `linux-tools-virtual`, but first I have run `sudo apt-get clean`